# Creating a square black div with a transparent circle in the middle

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a square div with a transparent circle in the middle. Behind this div there will be an image and the transparent circle will act as a 'window' to this image in the background.

Here is a working example: http://caavadesign.com/

This is what I tried, with no success:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:550px; float:left; background:#aaa;">
    <div style="width:250px; height:250px; margin:150px auto; border-radius:125px; background:transparent; border:1px solid #000;">
    </div>
</div>
```

I appreciate any advice on how to accomplish this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this absolutely can be done in css, just create a circle and set the `background-position` to `fixed`:

```
.window{
  background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/52/New_York_Midtown_Skyline_at_night_-_Jan_2006_edit1.jpg") center no-repeat fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L4unnna9/)

UPDATE USING YOUR CSS:

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L4unnna9/1/)

Answer (score 1):

they are using a background image

http://caavadesign.com/wp-content/themes/caava/img/section1_mask.png

Comment: +1, I was hoping this would not be necessary and there was a css solution out there :) guess there isnt one... thank you!